# Automatically size iframe(youtube video) using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, youtube

I am hoping to build a website like this https://www.emimacleod.com/totem.html. However the code I wrote does not work for iframe.

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row justify-content-between" id="basic-program-info-container">
    <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="title">
      <h1>ProjectName</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="program-info-container">
      <h2 class="title">Institute</h2>
      <h3 class="content">XXX University</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="program-info-container">
      <h2 class="title">Time</h2>
      <h3 class="content">2016 XXX - 2016 XXX</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="program-info-container">
      <h2 class="title">Team member</h2>
      <h3 class="content">Name1</h3>
      <h3 class="content">Name1</h3>
      <h3 class="content">Name1</h3>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="intro-content">Introduction</h2>
      <h2 class="intro-content">Introduction</h2>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/blahblahblah" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
   </div>
     </div>
```

I hope the whole iframe for youtube video will be inside the row. Also, the ratio between height and width should be the same when the screen change(adaptive design).

Answer (score 3):

See Bootstrap's [embed examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/), like so (if you're using bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8"></iframe>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 3 [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#responsive-embed).

---

And another thing, you're using bootstrap columns wrong. When you do `col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` you don't have to specify it to all versions, just the minor version and the lower version where it changes, which will be `col col-md-4` (by default all columns are `col-xs-12` on mobile and after `col-md-4` is used, it'll use it for `lg` too).

Answer (score 1):

Using `position: absolute;` and `width: 100%` in the iframe's style, you can make it use the full width of the bootstrap element. Set the `height` style attribute to your liking.

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row justify-content-between" id="basic-program-info-container">
    <div class="col col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="title">
      <h1>ProjectName</h1>
     </div>
     <div class="program-info-container">
      <h2 class="title">Institute</h2>
      <h3 class="content">XXX University</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="program-info-container">
      <h2 class="title">Time</h2>
      <h3 class="content">2016 XXX - 2016 XXX</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="program-info-container">
      <h2 class="title">Team member</h2>
      <h3 class="content">Name1</h3>
      <h3 class="content">Name1</h3>
      <h3 class="content">Name1</h3>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="intro-content">Introduction</h2>
      <h2 class="intro-content">Introduction</h2>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/blahblahblah" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="width: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe>
    </div>
   </div>
     </div>
     
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```